# How do I search for a question with a specific number of views?

Tags: support, search, views

I tried searching with the `views:n` syntax but that searches for questions with views greater than or equal to `n`. I was actually looking for questions with views less than or equal to it. How would I do that?

Comment: The range syntax is `[min][..[max]]`, so try `views:..n`.

Comment: @michaelb958 It works but for some reason it also shows questions with views greater than `n`. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that caching is at fault here - they were at `<= n` views last indexing pass, but have been viewed more since then.

Comment: How long is the caching period? I see a question that has 150 views on it when my search query was `views:..50` and that question was asked over 4 months ago! 0_o

Comment: ...oh wow. I don't know. We need a dev for this one.

Comment: Not able to reproduce, is this still happening? If so, what site?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is

```
views:0..n
```

This will search for questions that have *n* or less views.